# ORA-01008 no todas las variables han sido enlazadas, consulta C# Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, net

No, obtiene el valor de la variabla almacenada al hacer la consulta

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from DBA_USERS WHERE USER_ID = :validaman";
                                OracleParameter param1 = new OracleParameter("validaman", OracleDbType.Int16);
                                param1.Value = 1;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
                                OracleDataAdapter adp1 = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con);
```

arroja el mensaje

> ORA-01008 no todas las variables han sido enlazadas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que asignar el objeto `command` como parametro del `dataadapter`

```
string query = "select * from DBA_USERS WHERE USER_ID = :validaman";
OracleCommand cmd  = OracleCommand(query, con);

OracleParameter param1 = new OracleParameter("validaman", OracleDbType.Int16);
param1.Value = 1;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

OracleDataAdapter adp1 = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Si defines el commandtext y la conexion al dataadapter entonces no estas indicando el parametro porque se lo quedo el command